# Difference between the usage of 知恵 , 知能 and 知力

Tags: usage, words, nuances

I have read the sentence

```
"12歳の小児の知力しかない".
```

In this sentence , I would like to know the usage of   **知力**  .
In dictionary , it means "intelligence "
Can I use **知恵** or **知能** instead of  **知力**.
Is there any difference in usage between them.

With Regards,

Comment: Related [question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/what-are-the-nuances-between-these-three-terms-for-intelligence-%E7%9F%A5%E6%81%B5-%E3%81%A1%E3%81%88-%E3%80%80%E7%9F%A5%E8%83%BD-%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AE)

Comment: What's the context of the sentence? I'm reading it as "this person only has the brains of a 12 year old." Do you have the text before it?

Comment: @Louis This sentence means " This person has the mentality of a 12-year-old child " . I think so.

Comment: I think 気質 can be used for mentality/temperament.

Comment: @Flaw Is 気質 is more suitable than 知力 to show one's mentality?

Comment: I do not know if it's more suitable. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Standard Japanese learner disclaimer.]

To me, 知力 is more related to 知能 than it is to 知恵.

I think the 力 in 知力 implies mental *ability*, which is somewhat synonymous with the meaning of 能.

For 知恵, I can't do a comparison by kanji, but the definition seems more closely related to wisdom and knowledge (acquired intelligence), than it does to the abilities that come with talent (natural intelligence).

For example which is more applicable to an IQ test vs. a subject specific test like the [LSAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_School_Admission_Test)?

Comment: For a specific example of whether or not a word is interchangeable I think that deserves its own question.